# Can we update/delete document from elastic search db without id

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search db. With id property i am able to do update and delete but without id property (I mean another property of document which is unique) it is not working. Please let me know, can we do it or not.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Use `Delete_by_query` - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query to update

```
POST /indexName/typeName/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "name": "abc"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.description = 'Updated description'"
  }
}
```

Here is the query delete

```
POST /indexName/typeName/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "name": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is

1. Update by Query

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

```
POST twitter/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": { 
    "term": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Delete by Query

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

```
POST twitter/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "message": "some message"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...will try this.

Comment: _delete_by_query api is working fine. with _update_by_query i am getting parse exception. Using below query to update the description of documet whose name is abc. POST indexName/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{ 
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['description']='Updated Description'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
  "query": { 
    "term": {
      "name": "abc"
    }
  }
}

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "expected one of [inline], [file] or [stored] fields, but found none"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "expected one of [inline], [file] or [stored] fields, but found none"
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: tried this - POST /indexname/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "term": {
      "name": "abc"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.description = 'Updated'"
  }
} Running sucessfully but not updating the doc.

Comment: @RCS you need to probably call in the same fashion just replacing source with inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_delete_by_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query) API.

`_delete_by_query` gets a snapshot of the index when it starts and deletes what it finds using internal versioning. That means that you’ll get a version conflict if the document changes between the time when the snapshot was taken and when the delete request is processed. When the versions match the document is deleted.

Code snippet.

```
POST twitter/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "message": "some message"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _delete_by_query api is working fine. with _update_by_query i am getting parse exception. Using below query to update the description of documet whose name is abc. POST indexName/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed { "script": { "source": "ctx._source['description']='Updated Description'", "lang": "painless" } "query": { "term": { "name": "abc" } } }